# responsive tables doesnt work with laravel layout

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, responsive-design, laravel-blade

I use laravel framework and twitter-bootstrap and use blade & layouts to create my admin dashboard . 
all my tables work well in firefox in all media sizes  but for chrome they are displayed well just in larg media.

after many testing I found out that , without using layout and:

```
 @(extends('something'))
```

and just with for example:

```
user.`blade`.php
```

it works well again .

what's problem with layouts and chrome ??

thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be a problem with laravel and the templating engine. There is something amiss with the way you are setting up your templates. Hard to diagnose without more information.

Comment: thanks for reply :) . I want to put my code but it's so long . what is your idea about that my layout works with firefox and doesnt work with chrome?